# Dynamically Load Master Page from Database for MVC App

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

This is the scenario.  I want to be able to private label a website depending on the customer (stored as the subdomain).  Now as customers sign up, we will design/store the private labeling in the database.  I was hoping to store the private labeling as a master page file for each customer and load it on the fly from the database.

From what I have been searching, it doesn't seem possible.  I see that I can set the ViewPage.MasterPageFile property, but that is string path to the master file on the file system.

The only way I thought of doing this would be to on the edit of the private labeling, save the entry directly to a .master file out on the file system, but that seems hacky.

Thanks for any insight before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `VirtualPathProvider` sample code here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441

Comment: Finally came back around to working on this project, and this idea worked well

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an HTTP handler? You could pass a query param for the private labelling to output the master page HTML. Then you just set the ViewPage.MasterPageFile property to the handler + query param